# What i am missing? RecyclingView findViewById returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I don't get what I am missing. Can someone help me with this please?
**I tried invalidate caches. Delete all imports. Nothing is working.**

`The error i get is this:`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.circleapp/com.example.circleapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**This is my main MainActivity class **

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    NotesListAdapter notesListAdapter;
    List<Notes> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    RoomDB database;
    FloatingActionButton fabAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

When I cltrl + click on recycle_home it redirects me to the activity-main.xml.

Here, on recyclerView i get the nullpointer.

```
        recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_home);
        fabAdd.findViewById(R.id.fab_add);

        database = RoomDB.getInstance(this);

        notes = database.mainDAO().getAll();

        updateRecycler(notes);

        fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my main activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycle_home"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should look into viewbinding aswell it will help you when dealing with multiple views https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your views variables are indeed `null`.
Try like this:

```java
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_home);
fabAdd = findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
```